# Is it possible to use a PCI graphics card along side a PCE16 card with windows7?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

Is it possible to use a PCI graphics card along side a PCE16 card with windows7? i am trying to set up a 3 monitor system but am not having much luck.  i have a Palit 8400gs with DVI/VGA/HDMI thinking it would support 3 monitors but it doesn't.

Comment: Your card only supports 2 monitors at a time, but has 3 display options. You can only utilize two are a time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Windows supports multi monitor displays.  Your Palit 8400gs has 3 outputs, but only supports 2 outputs at a time.  You can add a 3rd (or more) display by adding another graphics card.

Your best bet is to add another GeForce based graphics card, as there are some people who report issues using cards with different drivers.